# PHP HTML preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
<div class="comment">
  <div class="pros">text1</div>
   <noindex>
    <div class="contras">text2</div>
   </noindex>
   <p>text3</p>
   <a few tags...>
</div>

 <div class="comment">
      <div class="pros">text1</div>
       <noindex>
        <div class="contras">text2</div>
       </noindex>
       <p>text3</p>
       <a few tags...>
    </div>
```

how to get the contents of the blocks  ?

text1

text2

text3

```
preg_match_all ('/<div class=\"comment\"><div class=\"pros\">(.*?)<\/div><noindex><div class=\"contras\">(.*?)<\/div><\/noindex><p>(.*?)<\/p><\/div>/Uisu',$content,$found4);
```

Parser does not offer

Comment: [use an HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/855532) - check out [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html-parser library aswell.

http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/samples.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $html = new DOMDocument();
 @$html->loadHTML($source)
 $xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
 $proslist = $xpath->query( "//*[contains(@class, 'pros')]" );
 foreach ($proslist as $list)
 {
    echo $list->nodeValue."\n";
 }
?>
```

This will help you in extracting the `text1` specified in the div with class `pros`.$source represents your html.As said in the previous comment you have to look in parsing html with php and I hope this [Reference link for parsing html with php](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) will help you.

Comment: $xpath->query( "//*[contains(@class, 'comment')]/p" ); get <p>text3</p> ?? receives 3 tag $mas[0]=text1;$mas[1]=text2;$mas[2]=text3; proceeding <div class="comment"> P.S. tag <p> not everywhere is